# About deploying Pods to Master in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Im newbie with Kubernetes. And I have 3 nodes cluster (1 master). I realized when I deploy pods, Kubernetes deploy them on worker nodes and not on master.

Just a few pods on master node which are used by Kubernetes. Does it make sense to deploy pods on the master node? Or do I avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deploying workload pods on master nodes is a way to put your whole cluster at risk

Primary role of master is cluster management. Already many components of k8 are running on master.Suppose If pods scheduled on master without limit of resources and pods are consuming all the resources( cpu or memory), then master and in turn whole cluster will be at risk.

So while designing Highly Available production cluster minimum 3 master, 3 etcd node are created and application pods are not scheduled on these nodes. Separate worker nodes added to assign workload

Answer (score 0):

Deploying workloads on the master node or control plane should be approached with caution as it can impact the stability and performance of your Kubernetes cluster. While it may be acceptable for testing or development purposes, it is not recommended for production environments due to potential resource contention and instability risks.

In such scenarios, it's advisable to utilize dedicated worker nodes for deploying workloads. Dedicated worker nodes help ensure the stability and reliability of your Kubernetes cluster by isolating application workloads from critical control plane components. This segregation minimizes the risk of disruptions to essential cluster operations and enhances overall cluster resilience.